# $(window).height() value is constant in firefox 22.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, window

I am using firefox version 22.0 in windows 8. I want to get the height of the window currently viewed instead of entire document. So, I used `$(window).height()` jQuery function. It always returns a constant value `616` even if the window is resized to its minimum, restored or maximized.

I also tried `$(document).height()` method of jQuery and `document.documentElement.clientHeight` property in javascript and they also return the same constant value `616`.

Is this behavior due to any settings I used in my browser?

Please tell me how can I get the actual window height in jquery or javascript.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Include *minimal* code with this behavior in a jsfiddle; post in here and link it.

Comment: Are you recalculating `$(window).height()` each time you resize?

Comment: @user2246674 I linked my code in following jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/GZQvy/4/

Comment: @Enigmadan, yes, I am recalculating window size every time window is resized

Comment: Your jsfiddle worked for me. I popped open Firebug, hit run on the jsfiddle, stretched the window a bit, hit run again, and got two different numbers on my console. I am also using version 22.0.

Comment: @Anandaraj Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/GZQvy/7/

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    console.log($(window).height()); 
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CLFVh/)

Answer (score 0):

Under Firefox 22 on Windows 7, this code worked just fine for me:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var h = $(window).height();
    alert(h);
}());
```

First reporting 1020 and then 774.

Perhaps you are running it outside of a document.ready (which I don't think should make a difference).

Outside of that, what operating system are you running on?

Comment: @Ana -- I don't have 8 available so I can't test that, but you might want to add that bit of info to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) magic property `innerHeight`? As in:

```
<div id="windowsize"></div>
<button onClick="document.getElementById('windowsize').innerHTML =
                            window.innerWidth+'x'+window.innerHeight;">Update</button>
```